# Rails Memcached Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I am using memcached in production on a high traffic website and have only just switched to using Rails.

I am using Rails 2.3.2.

My question is: Is caching of of queries done automatically with this version of Rails? Or do I have to explicitly cache these queries?

I have seen conflicting documentation on this issue, and I am afraid of having to restart memcached to see exactly what is happening.

The documentation on this w.r.t rails seems patchy. I would appreciate if you could also point out the best place to read up on this.

Thanks!
Vikram

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't explicitly set out and configured certain actions to be cached they won't be, so I would guess right now that you aren't actually using your memcached like you think you are.

As a starting point I'd recommend reading [this article](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/6/9/rails-2-1-now-with-better-integrated-caching) on the different methods of setting up caching within Rails.

I've also found [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/guestac752c/caching-memcached-and-rails) to be useful as well as [this excellent screencast](http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails).

If you're looking for help, it would be useful to know more of what you're trying to do: how write heavy is the application? How may pages / views / users are you trying to serve?

Comment: Thanks Mike. My question is specifically regarding queries. Are you saying that unless I specify it within my controllers what queries I want to cache, it won't happen automatically? I thought that in production, caching was enabled by default. 

I am worried now :). Memcached is using all of the allocated memory, so what is it caching exactly?

Comment: The term "cached" can mean different things in context. In production queries are "cached" meaning that at each request of the page if a query is called twice (or 20 times) only one actual request will be made against the server.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading the first article I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike,

So does that mean, in production, my queries are automatically being cached in memcached?

Comment: @Mike: Queries are cached in ActiveRecord's cache in the development environment too. You can see it in the log - it says "CACHE". I think Vikram is probably thinking of the production default setting whereby classes are cached i.e. not reloaded on each request.